# msys2 gcc: hello.cxx fatal error: FL/Fl.H: No such file or directory

Tags: fltk

yes there are a lot answers for this, but I'm getting it when using msys2 gcc.  I just compiled fltk and I'm not sure why when I run: `cpp hello.cxx $(fltk-config --compile) hello.exe` I get `hello.cxx fatal error: FL/Fl.H: No such file or directory`

This is not my first time building fltk and the first time I didn't run into the problem so I'm not sure why I am this time.

Answer (score 0):

Having a look [here](https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/basics.html), seems that the correct command is simply

```
fltk-config --compile hello.cpp
```

which will give you the executable `hello`.

The `fltk--config` already calls the compiler.